# How do I calculate r-squared using Python and Numpy?

Tags: python, math, statistics, numpy, curve-fitting

I'm using Python and Numpy to calculate a best fit polynomial of arbitrary degree.  I pass a list of x values, y values, and the degree of the polynomial I want to fit (linear, quadratic, etc.).

This much works, but I also want to calculate r (coefficient of correlation) and r-squared(coefficient of determination).  I am comparing my results with Excel's best-fit trendline capability, and the r-squared value it calculates.  Using this, I know I am calculating r-squared correctly for linear best-fit (degree equals 1).  However, my function does not work for polynomials with degree greater than 1.

Excel is able to do this.  How do I calculate r-squared for higher-order polynomials using Numpy?

Here's my function:

```
import numpy

# Polynomial Regression
def polyfit(x, y, degree):
    results = {}

    coeffs = numpy.polyfit(x, y, degree)
     # Polynomial Coefficients
    results['polynomial'] = coeffs.tolist()

    correlation = numpy.corrcoef(x, y)[0,1]

     # r
    results['correlation'] = correlation
     # r-squared
    results['determination'] = correlation**2

    return results
```

Comment: Note: you use the degree only in the calculation of coeffs.

Comment: tydok is correct.  You are calculating the correlation of x and y and r-squared for y=p_0 + p_1 * x.  See my answer below for some code that should work.  

If you don't mind me asking, what is your ultimate goal?  Are you doing model selection (choosing what degree to use)?  Or something else?

Comment: @leif -- The request boils down to "do it like Excel does".  I'm getting the feeling from these answers that the users may be reading too much into the r-squared value when using a non-linear best-fit curve.  Nonetheless, I'm not a math wizard, and this is the requested functionality.

Comment: side question : doesn't pandas corr() function return the r^"2 pearson coeffcient?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

From the [numpy.polyfit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) documentation, it is fitting linear regression.  Specifically, numpy.polyfit with degree 'd' fits a linear regression with the mean function

E(y|x) =  p_d * x**d + p_{d-1} * x **(d-1) + ... + p_1 * x + p_0

So you just need to calculate the R-squared for that fit.  The wikipedia page on [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) gives full details.  You are interested in R^2 which you can calculate in a couple of ways, the easisest probably being

```
SST = Sum(i=1..n) (y_i - y_bar)^2
SSReg = Sum(i=1..n) (y_ihat - y_bar)^2
Rsquared = SSReg/SST
```

Where I use 'y_bar' for the mean of the y's, and 'y_ihat' to be the fit value for each point.

I'm not terribly familiar with numpy (I usually work in R), so there is probably a tidier way to calculate your R-squared, but the following should be correct

```
import numpy

# Polynomial Regression
def polyfit(x, y, degree):
    results = {}

    coeffs = numpy.polyfit(x, y, degree)

     # Polynomial Coefficients
    results['polynomial'] = coeffs.tolist()

    # r-squared
    p = numpy.poly1d(coeffs)
    # fit values, and mean
    yhat = p(x)                         # or [p(z) for z in x]
    ybar = numpy.sum(y)/len(y)          # or sum(y)/len(y)
    ssreg = numpy.sum((yhat-ybar)**2)   # or sum([ (yihat - ybar)**2 for yihat in yhat])
    sstot = numpy.sum((y - ybar)**2)    # or sum([ (yi - ybar)**2 for yi in y])
    results['determination'] = ssreg / sstot

    return results
```

Comment: I just want to point out that using the numpy array functions  instead of list comprehension will be much faster, e.g. numpy.sum((yi - ybar)**2) and easier to read

Comment: According to wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination, the most general definition of R^2 is `R^2 = 1 - SS_err/SS_tot`, with `R^2 = SS_reg/SS_tot` being just a special case.

Comment: What about R squared for a non-linear least square function?

Answer (score 200):

A very late reply, but just in case someone needs a ready function for this:

[scipy.stats.linregress](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html)

i.e.

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(x, y)
```

as in @Adam Marples's answer.

Comment: It's reasonable to analyze with *coefficient of correlation*, and then to do the bigger job, *regression*.

Comment: This reply only works for linear regression, which is the simplest polynomial regression

Comment: Caution: r_value here is a Pearson's correlation coefficient, not R-squared. r_squared = r_value**2

Answer (score 87):

From yanl (yet-another-library) `sklearn.metrics` has an [`r2_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html) function;

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

coefficient_of_dermination = r2_score(y, p(x))
```

Comment: (Beware: "Default value corresponds to ‘variance_weighted’, this behaviour is deprecated since version 0.17 and will be changed to ‘uniform_average’ starting from 0.19")

Comment: r2_score in sklearn could be negative value, which is not the normal case.

Comment: Why is `r2_score([1,2,3],[4,5,7])` = `-16`?

Comment: One thing I like is it doesn't require training the model -- often I'm computing metrics from models trained in different environment.

Comment: @cz the formula for R2 is R2= 1 - (SSres/SStot)
here the calculation:
average of array 1 equals to 2, so.
((4-1)^2 + (5-2)^2 + (7-3)^2) / ((1-2)^2 + (2-2)^2 + (3-2)^2) = 17
1 - 17 = -16.

Comment: @cz I am assuming we are used to seeing a positive R2 because a real best fit line would never fit the points [1, 2, 3] with [4, 5, 7]

Comment: Why using Numpy do we get this?
y_true = [1,2,3]
y_pred = [4,5,7]
print(np.corrcoef(y_true, y_pred)[0,1]**2) # -> 0.9642857142857141

Answer (score 34):

I have been using this successfully, where x and y are array-like.

Note: for linear regression only

```
def rsquared(x, y):
    """ Return R^2 where x and y are array-like."""

    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(x, y)
    return r_value**2
```

Comment: This is not Perason's coefficient of determination, but the square of the correlation coefficient - something else entirely.

Comment: @liorr It's my understanding that the coefficient of determination is the square of the coefficient of correlation

Comment: I think this is only true when using linear regression: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination
"One class of such cases includes that of simple linear regression where r2 is used instead of R2. When only an intercept is included, then r2 is simply the square of the sample correlation coefficient (i.e., r) between the observed outcomes and the observed predictor values."

Comment: @liorr I am using r**2 from linear regression in my answer, scipy.stats.linregress, so it is correct

Comment: I think you are confusing linear regression, which can fit a polynomial of any degree, with fitting a linear *model*. You are using linear regression - but only to fit a polynomial of the first degree. So, you are not really answering the question, which was about the "...best fit polynomial of arbitrary degree". I suggest you edit your answer to reflect that it is only useful for polynomials of first degree (i.e., model function a + bx).

Comment: Ah yes I did not properly read the question. In my defence it was 9 years ago and I still haven't.

Comment: r-squared is already defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination
and it is so easy to calculate?!

Answer (score 29):

I originally posted the benchmarks below with the purpose of recommending `numpy.corrcoef`, foolishly not realizing that the original question already uses `corrcoef` and was in fact asking about higher order polynomial fits.  I've added an actual solution to the polynomial r-squared question using statsmodels, and I've left the original benchmarks, which while off-topic, are potentially useful to someone.

---

`statsmodels` has the capability to calculate the `r^2` of a polynomial fit directly, here are 2 methods...

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# Construct the columns for the different powers of x
def get_r2_statsmodels(x, y, k=1):
    xpoly = np.column_stack([x**i for i in range(k+1)])    
    return sm.OLS(y, xpoly).fit().rsquared

# Use the formula API and construct a formula describing the polynomial
def get_r2_statsmodels_formula(x, y, k=1):
    formula = 'y ~ 1 + ' + ' + '.join('I(x**{})'.format(i) for i in range(1, k+1))
    data = {'x': x, 'y': y}
    return smf.ols(formula, data).fit().rsquared # or rsquared_adj
```

To further take advantage of `statsmodels`, one should also look at the fitted model summary, which can be printed or displayed as a rich HTML table in Jupyter/IPython notebook.  The results object provides access to many useful statistical metrics in addition to `rsquared`.

```
model = sm.OLS(y, xpoly)
results = model.fit()
results.summary()
```

---

Below is my original Answer where I benchmarked various linear regression r^2 methods...

The [corrcoef](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) function used in the Question calculates the correlation coefficient, `r`, only for a single linear regression, so it doesn't address the question of `r^2` for higher order polynomial fits.  However, for what it's worth, I've come to find that for linear regression, it is indeed the fastest and most direct method of calculating `r`.

```
def get_r2_numpy_corrcoef(x, y):
    return np.corrcoef(x, y)[0, 1]**2
```

These were my timeit results from comparing a bunch of methods for 1000 random (x, y) points:

- Pure Python (direct `r` calculation)

  - 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.59 ms per loop
- Numpy polyfit (applicable to n-th degree polynomial fits)

  - 1000 loops, best of 3: 326 µs per loop
- Numpy Manual (direct `r` calculation)

  - 10000 loops, best of 3: 62.1 µs per loop
- Numpy corrcoef (direct `r` calculation)

  - 10000 loops, best of 3: 56.6 µs per loop
- Scipy (linear regression with `r` as an output)

  - 1000 loops, best of 3: 676 µs per loop
- Statsmodels (can do n-th degree polynomial and many other fits)

  - 1000 loops, best of 3: 422 µs per loop

The corrcoef method narrowly beats calculating the r^2 "manually" using numpy methods. It is >5X faster than the polyfit method and ~12X faster than the scipy.linregress.  Just to reinforce what numpy is doing for you, it's 28X faster than pure python.  I'm not well-versed in things like numba and pypy, so someone else would have to fill those gaps, but I think this is plenty convincing to me that `corrcoef` is the best tool for calculating `r` for a simple linear regression.

Here's my benchmarking code.  I copy-pasted from a Jupyter Notebook (hard not to call it an IPython Notebook...), so I apologize if anything broke on the way. The %timeit magic command requires IPython.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.api as sm
import math

n=1000
x = np.random.rand(1000)*10
x.sort()
y = 10 * x + (5+np.random.randn(1000)*10-5)

x_list = list(x)
y_list = list(y)

def get_r2_numpy(x, y):
    slope, intercept = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    r_squared = 1 - (sum((y - (slope * x + intercept))**2) / ((len(y) - 1) * np.var(y, ddof=1)))
    return r_squared
    
def get_r2_scipy(x, y):
    _, _, r_value, _, _ = stats.linregress(x, y)
    return r_value**2
    
def get_r2_statsmodels(x, y):
    return sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(x)).fit().rsquared
    
def get_r2_python(x_list, y_list):
    n = len(x_list)
    x_bar = sum(x_list)/n
    y_bar = sum(y_list)/n
    x_std = math.sqrt(sum([(xi-x_bar)**2 for xi in x_list])/(n-1))
    y_std = math.sqrt(sum([(yi-y_bar)**2 for yi in y_list])/(n-1))
    zx = [(xi-x_bar)/x_std for xi in x_list]
    zy = [(yi-y_bar)/y_std for yi in y_list]
    r = sum(zxi*zyi for zxi, zyi in zip(zx, zy))/(n-1)
    return r**2
    
def get_r2_numpy_manual(x, y):
    zx = (x-np.mean(x))/np.std(x, ddof=1)
    zy = (y-np.mean(y))/np.std(y, ddof=1)
    r = np.sum(zx*zy)/(len(x)-1)
    return r**2
    
def get_r2_numpy_corrcoef(x, y):
    return np.corrcoef(x, y)[0, 1]**2
    
print('Python')
%timeit get_r2_python(x_list, y_list)
print('Numpy polyfit')
%timeit get_r2_numpy(x, y)
print('Numpy Manual')
%timeit get_r2_numpy_manual(x, y)
print('Numpy corrcoef')
%timeit get_r2_numpy_corrcoef(x, y)
print('Scipy')
%timeit get_r2_scipy(x, y)
print('Statsmodels')
%timeit get_r2_statsmodels(x, y)
```

7/28/21 Benchmark results. (Python 3.7, numpy 1.19, scipy 1.6, statsmodels 0.12)

```
Python
2.41 ms ± 180 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
Numpy polyfit
318 µs ± 44.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
Numpy Manual
79.3 µs ± 4.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Numpy corrcoef
83.8 µs ± 1.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Scipy
221 µs ± 7.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
Statsmodels
375 µs ± 3.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: You are comparing 3 methods with fitting a slope and regression with 3 methods without fitting a slope.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that much... but now I feel silly for not reading the original question and seeing that it uses corrcoef already and is specifically addressing r^2 for higher order polynomials... now I feel silly for posting my benchmarks which were for a different purpose. Oops...

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution to the original question using `statsmodels`, and apologized for the needless benchmarking of linear regression r^2 methods, which I kept as interesting, yet off-topic info.

Comment: I still find the benchmark interesting because I didn't expect scipy's linregress to be slower than statsmodels which does more generic work.

Comment: Note, `np.column_stack([x**i for i in range(k+1)])` can be vectorized in numpy with `x[:,None]**np.arange(k+1)` or using numpy's vander functions which have reversed order in columns.

Comment: There is a typo, it should be `n = len(x_list)` for pure Python

Comment: Thanks @FabianSchn. - fixed

Comment: For what it's worth @Josef 2016 comment about linregress being slower than statsmodels is not true in 2021. I'm assuming linregress got faster. My 2021 benchmark results have been added to the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a function to compute  the *weighted* r-squared with  Python and Numpy (most of the code comes from sklearn):

```
from __future__ import division 
import numpy as np

def compute_r2_weighted(y_true, y_pred, weight):
    sse = (weight * (y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum(axis=0, dtype=np.float64)
    tse = (weight * (y_true - np.average(
        y_true, axis=0, weights=weight)) ** 2).sum(axis=0, dtype=np.float64)
    r2_score = 1 - (sse / tse)
    return r2_score, sse, tse
```

Example:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division 
import sklearn.metrics 

def compute_r2_weighted(y_true, y_pred, weight):
    sse = (weight * (y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum(axis=0, dtype=np.float64)
    tse = (weight * (y_true - np.average(
        y_true, axis=0, weights=weight)) ** 2).sum(axis=0, dtype=np.float64)
    r2_score = 1 - (sse / tse)
    return r2_score, sse, tse    

def compute_r2(y_true, y_predicted):
    sse = sum((y_true - y_predicted)**2)
    tse = (len(y_true) - 1) * np.var(y_true, ddof=1)
    r2_score = 1 - (sse / tse)
    return r2_score, sse, tse

def main():
    '''
    Demonstrate the use of compute_r2_weighted() and checks the results against sklearn
    '''        
    y_true = [3, -0.5, 2, 7]
    y_pred = [2.5, 0.0, 2, 8]
    weight = [1, 5, 1, 2]
    r2_score = sklearn.metrics.r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
    print('r2_score: {0}'.format(r2_score))  
    r2_score,_,_ = compute_r2(np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred))
    print('r2_score: {0}'.format(r2_score))
    r2_score = sklearn.metrics.r2_score(y_true, y_pred,weight)
    print('r2_score weighted: {0}'.format(r2_score))
    r2_score,_,_ = compute_r2_weighted(np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred), np.array(weight))
    print('r2_score weighted: {0}'.format(r2_score))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    #cProfile.run('main()') # if you want to do some profiling
```

outputs:

```
r2_score: 0.9486081370449679
r2_score: 0.9486081370449679
r2_score weighted: 0.9573170731707317
r2_score weighted: 0.9573170731707317
```

This corresponds to the [formula](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~adelle/Garvan/Assays/GoodnessOfFit.html) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170817185657/http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~adelle/Garvan/Assays/GoodnessOfFit.html)):

[image]

with f_i is the predicted value from the fit, y_{av} is the mean of the observed data y_i is the observed data value. w_i is the weighting applied to each data point, usually w_i=1. SSE is the sum of squares due to error and SST is the total sum of squares.

---

If interested, the code in R: https://gist.github.com/dhimmel/588d64a73fa4fef02c8f  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170807154523/https://gist.github.com/dhimmel/588d64a73fa4fef02c8f))

Answer (score 9):

Here's a very simple python function to compute R^2 from the actual and predicted values assuming y and y_hat are pandas series:

```
def r_squared(y, y_hat):
    y_bar = y.mean()
    ss_tot = ((y-y_bar)**2).sum()
    ss_res = ((y-y_hat)**2).sum()
    return 1 - (ss_res/ss_tot)
```

Comment: This formula gives a different answer than the numpy module for non-trivial data. This is likely because r_squared is an optimization problem with multiple solutions for the slope and offset of the best fit line.

Comment: The function above applies to any model, linear, nonlinear, ML etc… It only looks at the differences between the predicted values and the actual values. Each model will typically create a different R^2. Fitting a given model involves minimizing R^2 by varying the parameters of the model. A straight line fit for a curve with one independent variable and one dependent variable has a unique solution (the local minima == the global minima). More complicated models, particularly with additional independent variables, may have many local minima and finding the global minima may be very difficult.

Answer (score 6):

R-squared is a statistic that only applies to linear regression.

Essentially, it measures how much variation in your data can be explained by the linear regression.

So, you calculate the "Total Sum of Squares", which is the total squared deviation of each of your outcome variables from their mean. . .

[image: formula1]

where y_bar is the mean of the y's.

Then, you calculate the "regression sum of squares", which is how much your FITTED values differ from the mean

[image: formula2]

and find the ratio of those two.

Now, all you would have to do for a polynomial fit is plug in the y_hat's from that model, but it's not accurate to call that r-squared.

[Here](http://ask.metafilter.com/65278/Statistics-tell-me-about-rsquare-for-nonlinear-models) is a link I found that speaks to it a little.

Comment: This seems to be the root of my problem.  How does Excel get a different r-squared value for a polynomial fit vs. a linear regression then?

Comment: are you just giving excel the fits from a linear regression, and the fits from a polynomial model? It's going to calculate the rsq from two arrays of data, and just assume that you're giving it the fits from a linear model. What are you giving excel? What is the 'best fit trendline' command in excel?

Comment: It's part of the graphing functions of Excel.  You can plot some data, right-click on it, then choose from several different types of trend lines.  There is the option to see the equation of the line as well as an r-squared value for each type.  The r-squared value is also different for each type.

Comment: @Travis Beale -- you are going to get a different r-squared for each different mean function you try (unless two models are nested and the extra coeffecients in the larger model all work to be 0).  So of course Excel gives a different r-squared values.

@Baltimark -- this is linear regression so it is r-squared.

Answer (score 5):

The wikipedia article on [r-squareds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) suggests that it may be used for general model fitting rather than just linear regression.

Comment: Here's a good description of the issue with R2 for non-linear regression: http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/why-is-there-no-r-squared-for-nonlinear-regression

Answer (score 3):

Using the numpy module (tested in python3):

```
import numpy as np
def linear_regression(x, y): 
    coefs = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    ffit = np.poly1d(coefs)
    m = ffit[0]
    b = ffit[1] 
    eq = 'y = {}x + {}'.format(round(m, 3), round(b, 3))
    rsquared = np.corrcoef(x, y)[0, 1]**2
    return rsquared, eq, m, b

rsquared, eq, m, b = linear_regression(x,y)
print(rsquared, m, b)
print(eq)
```

Output:

> ```
> 0.013378252355751777 0.1316331351105754 0.7928782850418713 
> y = 0.132x + 0.793
> ```

Note: r² ≠ R² 
r² is called the "Coefficient of Determination"
R² is the square of the Pearson Coefficient

R², officially conflated as r², is probably the one you want, as it's a least-square fit, which is better than the simple fraction of sums that r² is. Numpy is not afraid to call it "corrcoef", which presupposes Pearson is the de-facto correlation coefficient.

Comment: I posted this solution because the wikipedia article formula gives a different result than the numpy solution. I believe the numpy module is correct because the wikipedia formula does not consider that multiple solutions exist (different slope and offsets of best fit line) and numpy apparently solves an actual optimization problem and not just calculate a fraction of sums. Evidence of the [simple] wikipedia formula being wrong is that it produces negative r_squared values, which means it's coming up with the wrong slope for the best fit line for non-trivial data.

Answer (score 1):

**You can execute this code directly, this will find you the polynomial, and will find you the R-value** you can put a comment down below if you need more explanation.

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
y = np.array([2,3,5,6,7,8])

p3 = np.polyfit(x,y,3) # 3rd degree polynomial, you can change it to any degree you want
xp = np.linspace(1,6,6)  # 6 means the length of the line
poly_arr = np.polyval(p3,xp)

poly_list = [round(num, 3) for num in list(poly_arr)]
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x, poly_list)
print(r_value**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

From scipy.stats.linregress source. They use the average sum of squares method.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

# average sum of squares:
ssxm, ssxym, ssyxm, ssym = np.cov(x, y, bias=1).flat

r_num = ssxym
r_den = np.sqrt(ssxm * ssym)
r = r_num / r_den

if r_den == 0.0:
    r = 0.0
else:
    r = r_num / r_den

    if r > 1.0:
        r = 1.0
    elif r < -1.0:
        r = -1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it directly in numpy==1.26 without any extra libraries by passing [`full=True`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.26/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html):

`np.polyfit(xs, ys, 1, full=True)`

Example:

```py
# make 5 (x, y) points with fake variation
xs = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
ys = np.array([0, 0.22, 0.55, 0.70, 1])

# ss_r: residuals – sum of squared residuals of the least squares fit.
#       ss_r will be 1D array if `ys` is 1D.
(m, b), ss_r, _, _, _ = np.polyfit(xs, ys, 1, full=True)
m, b, ss_r
```

`(0.9920000000000001    -0.001999999999999821   array([0.00568]))`

```py
# calculate line via `polyfit` then total sum of squares
# y = mx + b
r_ys = xs*m + b
ss_tot = np.sum((r_ys - np.mean(r_ys)) ** 2)

r_squared = 1 - (ss_r / ss_tot)
r_squared
```

`array([0.99630472])`