# MATLAB MEX can't find standard library with XCode 4.3 (Mac)

Tags: xcode, matlab, mex, xcode4.3

I am getting started with using MEX files for MATLAB (R2012a) compiled from C code (using XCode 4.3) on my Mac (running OSX 10.7.3, Lion). I have already installed the MATLAB provided [XCode patch](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-FR6LXJ/) which configures MATLAB to use the new llvm-gcc compiler under XCode 4.2+, but I am still getting the following error attempting to compile the example file using `mex timestwo.c`:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/extern/include/matrix.h:852:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
In file included from timestwo.c:1:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/extern/include/mex.h:161:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

The compilation then breaks

```
mex: compile of ' "timestwo.c"' failed.

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.
```

Clearly, the compiler can't find the standard library header directory, but what do I need to change to successfully compile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ah, found it!

The MATLAB provided template uses /Developer/... for the SDK location, but this changed under XCode4.3 to live under the XCode.app. To fix things, I had to edit my `~/.matlab/R2012a/mexopts.sh` file to set the SDKROOT directory to the new location.

To do this, search for SDKROOT in the mexopts.sh file and change it to read:

```
SDKROOT='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/'
```

Note, I chose the 10.7 sdk b/c I am on Lion. Use 10.6 if you are on Snow Leopard

Comment: Thanks for solving your problem **and** posting your answer. It worked for me!

Comment: @Tim: regarding your edit in [leif's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893657/how-do-i-calculate-r-squared-using-python-and-numpy/895063#895063). If you think that the answer can be improved, edit it, but add your code below so it's obvious which answer/code was accepted and what is the suggested improvement. Or, alternatively, you can add an answer of your own.

Comment: @ypercube: I added an error message I got in the same situation, so others can find it. I didn't have Matlab code, I was trying to compile a module (SeDuMi) on OS X 10.7.5 and got similar errors. I'm not sure if adding that clarifies things, which is why I added it to the initial question.

Comment: @Tim: Anyway, that edit was rejected (I think). So, make another try by editing or commenting. I'll delete these comments, too, Bryan sorry, for the unrelated discussion.

Answer (score 5):

I am running Mac Mountain Lion and Matlab R2012b, and the following solution worked for me: [Matlab 2012a Mex to work with Xcode 4.5 on Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643236/matlab-2012a-mex-to-work-with-xcode-4-5-on-mountain-lion)

To be precise,
I was getting the following errors:

`error: stdio.h: No such file or directory`

`error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory`

`error: math.h: No such file or directory`

So what I did to solve this issue:

I installed Xcode with Command Line Tools, and then edited the file "/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin/mexopts.sh" by:

changing CC from gcc-4.2 to llvm-gcc-4.2

changing CXX from gcc-4.2 to llvm-g++-4.2

setting SDKROOT to '/'

Then I ran "mex -setup" in MATLAB, chose number 1, and chose y to overwrite the old /Users/insertyournamehere/.matlab/R2012b/mexopts.sh

That solved it :)

Comment: your answer is not identical since the questioner who has posted the answer has not yet selected the answer. So can you please write it down again?

Comment: By choosing `1` you overwrite your setting you made before. So actually it is enough to rum `mex -setup`.

Answer (score 0):

You will find valuable information here: http://www.mathworks.fr/support/solutions/en/data/1-FR6LXJ/