# Matlab 2012a Mex to work with Xcode 4.5 on Mountain Lion

Tags: xcode, matlab, osx-mountain-lion, mex

I have Mountain Lion installed with Xcode 4.5 and Matlab 2012a. I installed and ran the patch supplied on the MathWorks website however I still received the following error:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/mex: line 305: llvm-gcc-4.2: command not found
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/mex: line 1326: llvm-gcc-4.2: command not found

mex: compile of ' "hello.c"' failed.
Error using mex (line 206)
```

Is there a known solution for that ?

> Solution: Open Xcode --> Preferences --> Downloads --> Install
>   "Command Line Tools"
>
> The MathWorks patch is still needed.  Resolved issue for me.

Comment: I've installed the command line tools and matlab patch and still not working.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to install XCode. I installed Command Line Tools and then edit the file "/Applications/MATLAB_R2012a.app/bin/mexopts.sh" and

changed CC from gcc-4.2 to llvm-gcc-4.2

changed CXX from gcc-4.2 to llvm-g++-4.2

set SDKROOT to '/'

It's done. Now, you just need to run "mex -setup" in MATLAB

Worked for me (Mac OSX 10.8.2, Command Line Tools - October 2012, MATLAB 2012a)

Comment: It is weired. doing the last step 'mex -setup' has reverted some of my changes to mexopts.sh. Nonetheless, the above steps exactly worked for me. Thanks Hadi!