# Standard C libraries not found when compiling mex files in Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, mex

Update: I installed XCode and changed SDKROOT in mexopts.sh to reflect the actual path as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845762/matlab-mex-cant-find-standard-library-with-xcode-4-3-mac), but I still get this error when I include mex.h:

```
In file included from /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:294,
                 from /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/mex.h:58,
                 from test.c:2:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/tmwtypes.h:61:21: error: float.h: No such file or directory

    mex: compile of ' "test.c"' failed.
```

---

I'm trying to compile a trivial C file for use in Matlab through mex, but it seems to never find default libraries that I know are installed.  For instance, trying to compile the following:

```
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

gives me the error:

```
test.c:1:20: error: string.h: No such file or directory
mex: compile of ' "test.c"' failed.
```

even though it compiles fine using gcc.  Worse, when I try to include mex.h like so:

```
#include "mex.h"
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
In file included from /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/mex.h:58,
                 from test.c:2:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:293:20: error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:294,
                 from /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/mex.h:58,
                 from test.c:2:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/tmwtypes.h:43:20: error: limits.h: No such file or directory
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/tmwtypes.h:46:21: error: stdbool.h: No such file or directory
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/tmwtypes.h:61:21: error: float.h: No such file or directory
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/tmwtypes.h:777:2: error: #error "This code must be compiled using a 2's complement representation for signed integer values"
In file included from /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:294,
                 from /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/mex.h:58,
                 from test.c:2:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/tmwtypes.h:823: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'CHAR16_T'
In file included from /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/mex.h:58,
                 from test.c:2:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:319: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'mxChar'
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:375: error: expected ')' before 'n'
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:383: error: expected ')' before 'n'
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:397: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'size_t'
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:590: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'mxGetNumberOfElements'
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:632: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:688: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'mxGetM'
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:700: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'mxGetN'
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:750: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'mxGetElementSize'
In file included from /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/mex.h:58,
             from test.c:2:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:851:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:1072: error: expected ')' before 'm'
In file included from test.c:2:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/mex.h:91: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'size_t'
In file included from test.c:2:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/extern/include/mex.h:161:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

    mex: compile of ' "test.c"' failed.
```

I assume mex isn't looking in the right place for these libraries, or the installation is corrupt somehow, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Mac OSX Mountain Lion + XCode 4.5.2, Matlab R2012b, gcc 4.2.1

Comment: Can you compile if you don't even include a single library?

Comment: It compiles fine if I don't include any libraries, and remove any reference to mex-specific types like mxArray.

Answer (score 2):

The include file(s) need to be in your *PATH* (type *path* to show these folders) unless you specifically include them using *mex -Ipathname*. You can click 'File->Set Path' and add the folder containing your string.h.

Answer (score 1):

Just to share, I had similar problem. I was running same version of Matlab and was looking at this page and could not find the answer. I found my answer here: [Matlab 2012a Mex to work with Xcode 4.5 on Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643236/matlab-2012a-mex-to-work-with-xcode-4-5-on-mountain-lion)

Answer (score 1):

Specify the following options with the `mex` command and it will work fine. Please be sure you have standard header files in the following folder, otherwise update accordingly:

```
mex -I'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt'.
```

If you get past this error, it might crib for .lib also. Include that similarly

```
mex -I'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt' -L'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\x64'
```