# Why do coefficient of determination, R², implementations produce different results?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, coefficient-of-determination

When attempting to implement a python function for calculating the coefficient of determination, R², I noticed I got wildly different results depending on whose calculation sequence I used.

The [wikipedia page on R²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) gives a seemingly very clear explanation as to how R² should be calculated. My numpy interpretation of what is being said on the wiki page is the following:

```
def calcR2_wikipedia(y, yhat):
    # Mean value of the observed data y.
    y_mean = np.mean(y)
    # Total sum of squares.
    SS_tot = np.sum((y - y_mean)**2)
    # Residual sum of squares.
    SS_res = np.sum((y - yhat)**2)
    # Coefficient of determination.
    R2 = 1.0 - (SS_res / SS_tot)
    return R2
```

When I try this method with a target vector *y* and a vector of modeled estimates *yhat*, this function produces an R² value of -0.00301.

However, the accepted answer from [this stackoverflow post discussing how to calculate R²](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893657/how-do-i-calculate-r-squared-using-python-and-numpy), gives the following definition:

```
def calcR2_stackOverflow(y, yhat):
    SST = np.sum((y - np.mean(y))**2)
    SSReg = np.sum((yhat - np.mean(y))**2)
    R2 = SSReg/SST
    return R2
```

Using that method with the same *y* and *yhat* vectors as before, I now get an R² of 0.319.

Moreover, in the same stackoverflow post, a lot people of seem to be in favor of calculating the R² with the scipy module like this:

```
import scipy
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(yhat, y)
R2 = r_value**2
```

Which in my case produces 0.261.

So my question is: why are R² values produced from seemingly well-accepted sources radically different from each other? And what is the correct way of calculating R² between two vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Definitions

This is a notation abuse that often leads to misunderstanding. You are comparing two different coefficients:

- [Coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) (usually noted as `R^2`) which can be used for any OLS regression not only linear regression (OLS is linear with regards of fit parameters not the function itself);
- [Pearson Correlation Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) (usually noted as `r` or `r^2` when squared) which is used for linear regression only.

If you read carefully the introduction of Coefficient of determination on Wikipedia page, you will see that it is discussed there, it starts as follow:

> There are several definitions of R2 that are only sometimes
> equivalent.

### MCVE

You can confirm that classical implementation of those score return expected results:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from sklearn import metrics

np.random.seed(12345)
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1001)
yh = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(x, [1, 2])
e = np.random.randn(x.size)
yn = yh + e
```

Then your function `calcR2_wikipedia` (`0.9265536406736125`) returns the coefficient of determination, it can be confirmed as it returns the same as [sklearn.metrics.r2_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score):

```
metrics.r2_score(yn, yh) # 0.9265536406736125
```

In the other hand the [scipy.stats.linregress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) returns the correlation coefficient (valid for linear regression only):

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = scipy.stats.linregress(yh, yn)
r_value # 0.9625821384210018
```

Which you can cross confirm by it's definition:

```
C = np.cov(yh, yn)
C[1,0]/np.sqrt(C[0,0]*C[1,1]) # 0.9625821384210017
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’m still somewhat confused, could you please verify these two points: 
When you said “`calcR2_wikipedia` returns the coefficient of correlation”, did you actually mean coefficient of determination? 

And the `sklearn.metrics.r2_score` function, does that return the coefficient of determination, R2, despite being named r2? (which would be the notation of a squared pearsons correlation coeff.)

Comment: @Petahanks indeed it is coefficient of determination R2 (caps letter, corrected). As stated in documentation and Wikipedia it is the r or rho value (linear correlation) not the r2 (lower case, the sign gives you an extra information about the correlation).

Comment: One aspect of the coefficient of determination (R^2) which makes it particularly useful is that values less than zero denote models which are worse than just returning the mean of the response variable(s).