# Recover SAS output for ANOVA analysis using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
m1 = [3129, 3000, 2865, 2890]
m2 = [3200, 3300, 2975, 3150]
m3 = [2800, 2900, 2985, 3050]
m4 = [2600, 2700, 2600, 2765]
t_dict = {'mix1': m1, 'mix2': m2, 'mix3': m3, 'mix4': m4}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(t_dict, orient='index', columns=['sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3', 'sample4'])
```

When we apply SAS on this data we get the following table:

Is there any way to get an output like what SAS generates using Python?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of. ANOVA is a complex process not a single "thing", therefore the table is complex the same way and for programming that you'll need to assemble it from tiny parts:

Try to utilize [SciPy](https://scipy.org/install.html) (`pip install scipy`, or try it [in Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/try)) as it mostly covers these models and statistical properties.

**F-value and Pr > F** ([`f_oneway()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f_oneway.html)):

```py
import scipy.stats
print(scipy.stats.f_oneway(m1, m2, m3, m4))
# F_onewayResult(statistic=12.728107492613294, pvalue=0.0004887151309914456)
```

For R-squared there needs to be a model and distinguishing between `Y` and Xn values. From the question I have zero clue which is which.

Perhaps you're looking to fit it into [`scipy.stats.linregress()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) from which you can then assemble errors and R-squared values, thus the rest of the table.

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/895063/5994041) for calculating R-squared with numpy and [this article](https://www.pythonfordatascience.org/anova-python/) which follows the process of ANOVA in detail which you can follow with the rest of the data and the relationship between its parts.

Answer (score 1):

"SAS" is a software, I'm not sure what "apply SAS" means. I see in the image there is a ANOVA test, so I assume you want to apply ANOVA for your data using python.

`statsmodel` package is a useful library for statistics. If you are looking for ANOVA test, check out [statsmodels' anova](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/anova.html) and [interactions with anova](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/interactions_anova.html) pages.

Here at StackOverflow we are happy to guide you towards the solution, but we won't write the answer for you. Give `statsmodels` a shoot on your own, and ask a more specific question if you get stuck in the process.