# How to define goodness of fit in curve_fit()?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, model-fitting, goodness-of-fit

Hello guys I have used "**curve_fit()**" to fit my data to voigt function in the following way:

```
def voigt(x,a,m,s,g):
    z = (x-m+complex(0,g))/(s*math.sqrt(2))
    d = wofz(z)
    return (a*d.real)/(s*math.sqrt(2*pi))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(voigt, xval, yval, bounds=([0,25,0,0.012], [99,37., 0.01, 2.5]), maxfev =10000)
```

I need to calculate how god is my fit with the data I obtained, How can I achieve this?

Comment: from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) to calculate 1 std on the parameters use ```perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))```

Comment: Okay, I see, the better fit is if I have lower values for it right?

Comment: Yes, lower errors mean better confidence in these parameters. If you want to judge the entire fit, you can use R-squared, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30804603/8310295.